# Is there any Free well reputed Open Source Business Intelligence tool?

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis, statistics, analytics, business-intelligence

I need some alternatives for PowerBI, Tableau. And It should be completely Open Source.

Comment: As of now, there is no free open source for visualization.

Comment: What about Facets, it's on Github here `https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets`, by Google research subsidiary PAIR-Code

Answer (score 1):

I'm astonished no one replied to you...

[Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/) is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, I'm also needed the tool to be containerized. I found ELK stack (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) the closest and better.

Kibana is used (among other things) to visualize indexes stored in Elasticsearch, data can be ingested from almost any source to Elasticsearch using Logstash. I mention some of the advantages and disadvantages according to my vision:

**Cons:**

- You need some knowledge of several things to set everything up correctly.
- The easiest way to make visualizations are quite limited. You need some knowledge to make complex visualizations.
- You can't do `joins` among indexes, you need to denormalice the data. You need some effort to prepare the structure of data.

**Pros:**

- Queries are very very fast.
- You can make queries of geografical data like "points within a polygon" very fast.
- It has a powerfull full text query capability.
- ElasticSearch is an API for Lucene, the results of queries, even queries made by KIbana are returned in a json. You can use that requests as input for any other data visualization tool or you can use that as an API of raw data.
- In my case, ElasticSearch indexes serves as the location of consolidated data, I have Oracle and Postgres with normalized data, queries of consolidated data are not consuming resources of the place where data is processing.